# I can't get user's mobile phone number using facebook login in react native

Tags: reactjs, facebook, firebase, react-native, expo

I have read many documentations on facebook mobile number but most of them are very old be like answered in 2012 and so. I am still curious that does Facebook still provides a phone number of the user? 
And if it does how to retrieve that through react native and I am using Firebase as a database.

Presently I am using this permission to get the users credentials.

```
 {
        permissions: ["public_profile", "email","user_mobile_phone"]
      }
```

Also I am facing a issue that If a user has only phone number and unconfirmed email address then all the necessary detials i.e email ID and phone number are null.
How to resolve thi issue.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by “still” - AFAIK they never did provide access to the user’s phone number, at least not for normal 3rd-party apps. (Some “partners” like Uber seem to get a special deal.) If you can’t get an email from the API, but your app needs some way to get in contact with users - then implement a step to _ask_ them for an email address. (Of course, confirmation of that address would then be up to you as well.)

Comment: Okay, thank you but I read somewhere in the documentation that facebook does provides an email address and phone number! I am not sure though

Comment: No, only the email address is a available, but no phone number.